# Erro em CASE no WHERE do ORACLE

Tags: oracle

Estou tentando utilizar a função case na cláusula where no Oracle mas essa parte da query gera um erro. É possível utilizar essa função pra determinar qual join vai ser feito?

```
AND (CASE 
WHEN (t1.cd1 IS NOT NULL) THEN (t2.cd1 = t1.cd1 )
ELSE (t3.cd2 = t1.cd2)
END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa de CASE para isso, basta usar lógica booleana comum.

```
AND(
(t1.cd1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.cd1 = t1.cd1)
OR
(t3.cd2 = t1.cd2)
)
```

BTW, sim! você pode fazer algo tipo:

```
where column_1 = <Some_value>
and (case when p_call_location = 'A' and column_2 like '%ABC%' then 'VALID'
when p_call_location = 'B' and column_2 Not Like '%ABC%' then 'VALID'
when p_call_location = 'C' then column_3 like '%EFG%'
else 'INVALID'
END) = 'VALID';
```

Mas desconfio que usar pura lógica (sem case) é (possivelmente) melhor

Obs: Quando der um erro (provavelmente no seu caso um erro de sintaxe) posta o erro junto pois facilita dar uma resposta

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo assim:

```
AND CASE WHEN (t1.cd1 IS NOT NULL) 
         THEN t2.cd1 
         ELSE t3.cd2
    END = t1.cd2
```

Na primeira condição se o t1.cd1 não for nulo, ele traz a coluna t2.cd1, se a t1.cd1 for nulo, ele traz a coluna t3.cd2. Depois ele compara o valor com a coluna t1.cd2